# dynamically sizing an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I have an image that I'm sizing with a percentage of it's container, what I would like to do is to lower that percentage when the container is bigger (window is maxed) and a higher number when the window is shrunk.

Rather then write a script using some type of switch or multiple if statements I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on a possible math formula solution kind of thing.

For example a width 1080px would have a result of 1% and
a width of 358px would have 5%

Comment: You want to choose the specific percentages at various widths? Or you don't care what the percentages are at various widths?

Comment: if you want to do it for a continuous range (i.e.: every browser width  results in a different percentage) you need to do it with javascript. If on the other hand you want to use discrete steps, you could use mediaqueries as suggested by @beautifulcoder. (of course you could write a script for discrete steps as well, but you explicitly state yo want to avoid that, which seems reasonable.). So in short, please be more specific what you want to accomplish. for 95% of cases it seems that mediaqueries would fit just fine imho.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid media queries or multiple if statements kind of thing, thought maybe some type of math formula would work started looking into the formula for gravity and figured I was heading in the right direction, trying to find the right numbers to put in the formula though to get the results desired wasn't really panning out though, guess I'll just use a switch and script...

Thanks for the replies I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use media queries for this with varying width sizes. There is really no magic mathematical formula for this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

Use the following media query to achieve this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: xxxpx) and (min-width: yyypx){
      #container img{
        width: z%;
      }
    }
```

Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
          #container img{
            width: 5%;
          }
        }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width:401px){
          #container img{
            width: 3%;
          }
        }

@media only screen and (min-width:1001px){
          #container img{
            width: 1%;
          }
        }
```

**Replace the pixel values with the desired values and set multiple range as required**

For more on media query read this:
http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/